# Put a text in the middle of a column

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{the title}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
the title & number \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{\mylen}|}{very very very very long} & 100 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It draws a tabular as follows (please ignore the font and background colours)

[image]

Does anyone know how to put `100` in the `vertical` middle of the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `m` column type from `array` package instead of `p` type..

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{the title}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
the title & number \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{\mylen}|}{very very very very long} & 100 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225482/11232), you may use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\mylen}` here too to avoid overfull boxes.

Comment: it works... but I don't understand why 100 is put in the middle, while `m` is used over `very very very very long`...

Comment: @SoftTimur That's how it works. Other columns are aligned to the center of `m` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multirow package for this, but only *after* you know how many lines your long entry will take, because you have to tell multirow how many lines it should span for vertical centering.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{the title}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
the title & number \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{\mylen}|}{very very very very long} & \multirow{5}{*}{100} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```